# iOS Core Data managed object update not persisted to sqlite db

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios5, persistence, nsmanagedobject

when I try to Save an updated managedobject the changes don't get persisted to the sqlite db.
In the appDelegate I create the managedObjectContext etc and I am passing a ref to this to the detailviewcontroller in which the update takes place.
I wonder whether this is root cause of the issue - can anyone please advise on this?
Thanks.

```
-(void)saveManagedObject:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext]; // this was passed earlier

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"jobDescription = %@", self.jobDescription.text ];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Job" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate ];

    Job *reqJob = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] lastObject];

    [reqJob setSummary:self.summary.text];

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error updating %@ - error:%@",self.detailItem.jobDescription, error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually Do you need to fetch or save into core data?What is 'Task' class in your code?After you fetched ,put it into an array and check array having values or not?

Comment: Hi R.A., in the application when I move to another record and back again the update to summary is recorded. But when I restart the app it has not been recorded to sqlite.

Comment: Sorry (twice). I pasted the code incorrectly and have corrected it now.

Comment: I've discovered that there was a subtle problem with the job class which caused this. I will enter a full answer when StackOverflow permits me in 4 hours time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've solved the problem and in case anyone experiences the same I'll detail the solution here.
It turns out that I hadn't created the Job NSManagedObject class correctly (or I changed it at some point to make it fail to function).

As a consequence it seems that perhaps Core Data was unable to detect that a change had occurred in the object and therefore did not write anything back to the database.
I regenerated the class for this managedobject entity via XCode and all is well.

Thanks for looking at my post R.A. - sorry that it was a bit of a waste for you.

Comment: Its ok. Actually Your Question was not clear to me. So that couldn't help you that time. Anyway, accept your answer itself.